# Confusion regarding direct and indirect propotion.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ratio

> If $x\ \propto \ y$ and $y\ \propto \ \dfrac{1}{z}$, then which of the following is correct

$\color{green}{a.)\ x\ \propto \ z} \\
b.)\ x\ \propto \ \dfrac{1}{z}$

I did

$x=k_{1}y,\ y=\dfrac{k_{2}}{z} \\
x=\dfrac{k_{1}k_{2}}{z} \\
x=\dfrac{k_{3}}{z} \\
x\propto \dfrac{1}{z} \\
$

But the answer given in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BM7L9dlbS6w) is $x\ \propto \ z$

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths up to $12$th grade.

Comment: Your math looks correct. I can't watch the video at the moment to see their reasoning; can you summarize what they say about the problem?

Comment: The math from the video doesn't make sense, as someone pointed out in the commentary section.

Comment: For example he says that if $\frac{x}{y}=constant$ and $y \times z = constant$, then $\dfrac{x}{y\times z} = constant$, which is false.